# How to remove all cy.route from beforeEach in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm creating a lot of tests for application in my firm. Before each test I need to create a state to work on it, and it's always the same, so I created some routes in my own method and then in support/index.js file I created beforeEach that looks like this

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.server();
    cy.mockSearches(SHORTEN_SEARCHES); // this only creates mocks
    cy.loginAdmin();
});
```

And in 99% percent of tests it's working fine, but there is one test, that needs to work on real data. What should I do? Is there a way to ignore global beforeEach? I guess I can move this part of code to each test before each, but that's code repetition? Or maybe I should override this cy.route with empty responses?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to your `beforeEach()` to exit before your setup:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    if (shouldUseRealData) return;
    cy.server();
    cy.mockSearches(SHORTEN_SEARCHES); // this only creates mocks
    cy.loginAdmin();
});
```

As stated in the docs about [environment variables](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Setting), you can set an environment variable in different ways. One way would be to set it in your command line when calling cypress run:

```
cypress run --env use_mock=true
```

And then you would use it with `Cypress.env('use_mock')`.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    if (Cypress.env('use_mock')) {
        cy.server();
        cy.mockSearches(SHORTEN_SEARCHES); // this only creates mocks
        cy.loginAdmin();
    }
});
```

Comment: And how I should pass this variable into beforeEach that is called before each test? I was thinking about solution like this, but I didn't know how to send variable from test to beforeEach.

Comment: Does my edited answer help? Were you able to create and use an environment variable to be used in your beforeEach()?